# How to extract text from multiple columns in R and paste into same columns?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a dataset which contains several columns in the below format.

| et_intro | et_ed_eng |
| --- | --- |
| (ID 1) Yes I understand | (ID -1) None of the above |
| (ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey | (ID 1) Exercise |

I want to write a simple statement in R (preferably tidyverse-friendly) that produces the below.

| et_intro | et_ed_eng |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 |

---

**Data**

```r
ets_e <- ets_p <- structure(
        list(
                `Scheduled Time` = c(
                        "2020-11-10 11:31:09 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 19:49:06 EST",
                        "2020-11-13 21:07:44 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 14:05:48 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 17:14:14 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 21:22:09 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 15:26:42 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 13:42:15 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:18:16 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:20:17 EST",
                        "2020-11-27 15:47:27 EST"
                ),
                `Issued Time` = c(
                        "2020-11-10 11:31:09 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 19:49:06 EST",
                        "2020-11-13 21:07:44 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 14:05:48 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 17:14:14 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 21:22:09 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 15:26:42 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 13:42:15 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:18:16 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:20:17 EST",
                        "2020-11-27 15:47:27 EST"
                ),
                `Response Time` = c(
                        "2020-11-10 11:31:36 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 19:49:53 EST",
                        "2020-11-13 21:08:13 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 14:07:16 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 17:15:24 EST",
                        "2020-11-12 21:22:56 EST",
                        "2020-11-11 15:28:34 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 13:42:25 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:18:55 EST",
                        "2020-11-25 16:22:08 EST",
                        "2020-11-27 15:47:44 EST"
                ),
                `Duration (minutes)` = c(
                        26.52,
                        47.758,
                        29.752,
                        87.806,
                        69.313,
                        46.894,
                        111.483,
                        10.768,
                        38.319,
                        111.159,
                        17.287
                ),
                Location = c(
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown",
                        "Unknown"
                ),
                et_intro = c(
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey (you can exit the current survey)",
                        "(ID 1) Yes I understand",
                        "(ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey (you can exit the current survey)",
                        "(ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey (you can exit the current survey)"
                ),
                et_ed_eng = c(
                        "(ID -1) None of the above",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 1) Binge eating",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ed_eng_other = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                                    NA, NA, NA),
                et_ed_whyb = c(
                        NA,
                        "(ID 4) Because I don't know how to control my eating & (ID 5) Because binge eating feels good",
                        "(ID 5) Because binge eating feels good",
                        "(ID 3) To cope with my emotions & (ID 5) Because binge eating feels good",
                        "(ID 4) Because I don't know how to control my eating & (ID 5) Because binge eating feels good",
                        "(ID 4) Because I don't know how to control my eating & (ID 5) Because binge eating feels good",
                        "(ID 1) I went too long without eating or restricted my eating too much",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 1) I went too long without eating or restricted my eating too much",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ed_whyb_other = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                                     NA, NA, NA),
                et_ed_bplan = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, NA, 0, NA,
                                NA),
                et_ed_rstr = c(
                        "(ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate",
                        "(ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like & (ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate",
                        "(ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like",
                        "(ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate & (ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like",
                        "(ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate & (ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like",
                        "(ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like & (ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate",
                        "(ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 3) Tried to delay eating & (ID 2) Tried to avoid eating certain foods that you like & (ID 1) Tried to limit the amount that you ate",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ed_rstr_lim = c(
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 1) Yes",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        NA,
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ed_rstr_av = c(
                        NA,
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 1) Yes",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ed_rstr_del = c(NA,
                                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "(ID 2) No", NA, NA),
                et_ex_eng = c(
                        "(ID 1) Yes",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 1) Yes",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        "(ID 2) No",
                        NA,
                        NA
                ),
                et_ex_dc = c(2, NA, 3,
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                et_ex_sw = c(3, NA, 3, NA, NA,
                             NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                et_ex_comp = c(1, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA,
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
        ),
        row.names = c(NA,-11L),
        class = c("tbl_df",
                  "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Comment: @akrun Done, sorry about that!

Comment: when you have many ID's eg `(ID 1) & (ID 5) do you need both or as the first one or the second one? And if both, do you need them in a list/vector or even as a string?

Comment: @Onyambu If it's possible I'd have both IDs in the same column, separated by a comma (e.g., "1,5").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(gsub("^.*?(-?\\d+).*$", "\\1", .x))))
#>   et_intro et_ed_eng
#> 1        1        -1
#> 2        2         1
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(et_intro = c("(ID 1) Yes I understand", 
"(ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey"
), et_ed_eng = c("(ID -1) None of the above", "(ID 1) Exercise"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df
#>                                       et_intro                 et_ed_eng
#> 1                      (ID 1) Yes I understand (ID -1) None of the above
#> 2 (ID 2) No I meant to open a different survey           (ID 1) Exercise
```

---

**EDIT**

With the newly added data in the question, it is clear a bit of work needs to be done in selecting the correct columns rather than selecting `everything()`:

```r
ets_e %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character) & starts_with("et_"),
                ~as.numeric(gsub("^.*?(-?\\d+).*$", "\\1", .x))))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 19
#>    `Scheduled Time` `Issued Time` `Response Time` `Duration (minu~ Location et_intro
#>    <chr>            <chr>         <chr>                      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 2020-11-10 11:3~ 2020-11-10 1~ 2020-11-10 11:~             26.5 Unknown         1
#>  2 2020-11-12 19:4~ 2020-11-12 1~ 2020-11-12 19:~             47.8 Unknown         1
#>  3 2020-11-13 21:0~ 2020-11-13 2~ 2020-11-13 21:~             29.8 Unknown         1
#>  4 2020-11-11 14:0~ 2020-11-11 1~ 2020-11-11 14:~             87.8 Unknown         1
#>  5 2020-11-12 17:1~ 2020-11-12 1~ 2020-11-12 17:~             69.3 Unknown         1
#>  6 2020-11-12 21:2~ 2020-11-12 2~ 2020-11-12 21:~             46.9 Unknown         1
#>  7 2020-11-11 15:2~ 2020-11-11 1~ 2020-11-11 15:~            111.  Unknown         1
#>  8 2020-11-25 13:4~ 2020-11-25 1~ 2020-11-25 13:~             10.8 Unknown         2
#>  9 2020-11-25 16:1~ 2020-11-25 1~ 2020-11-25 16:~             38.3 Unknown         1
#> 10 2020-11-25 16:2~ 2020-11-25 1~ 2020-11-25 16:~            111.  Unknown         2
#> 11 2020-11-27 15:4~ 2020-11-27 1~ 2020-11-27 15:~             17.3 Unknown         2
#> # ... with 13 more variables: et_ed_eng <dbl>, et_ed_eng_other <lgl>, et_ed_whyb <dbl>,
#> #   et_ed_whyb_other <lgl>, et_ed_bplan <dbl>, et_ed_rstr <dbl>, et_ed_rstr_lim <dbl>,
#> #   et_ed_rstr_av <dbl>, et_ed_rstr_del <dbl>, et_ex_eng <dbl>, et_ex_dc <dbl>,
#> #   et_ex_sw <dbl>, et_ex_comp <dbl>
```

Comment: I tried adapting your answer to my code (given the differences b/w what I'd provided as an example and the actual code), and I ran into a few different error messages, so I provided dput output in OP. Sorry about that!

Comment: @apaynereichert see my update. You need a way of specifying the columns to which you want to apply this logic. I think you just need all character columns starting with `et_`, but if necessary you can add further logical tests. Ultimately it may be easier to specify the actual column names, passing them inside `vars()` and passed as the first argument of `across`

Comment: Some of the columns contain many ID's. OP is not clear as to whether to include all the ID's or rather a section of them

Comment: Thanks very much @AllanCameron. Onyambu made a good point; I do need the instances of multiple IDs to have both IDs in the same cell.